# How do I organize this data into structures in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-struct

Say for `n=5`, the following code gives me a plot for `n` randomly generated nodes. These nodes are not structures (just plotted points), but I want to assign every node a message just as I did for `sink` and `source` and keep track of the nodes identity and location.

For example, if `node 4` has (x,y) coordinates `(.3452 , .5463)`, I want to assign `node 4` a `msg` and `temp_value` as well. How can I do this?

#### Code:

```
n = input('No. of Nodes:');

sink = [0 0];
source = [1 1];

node = rand(n,2)
x = node(:,1);
y = node(:,2);

x1 = sink(:,1);
y1 = sink(:,1);

x2 = source(:,1);    
y2 = source(:,1);

plot(x,y,'o')
hold on

plot(x1,y1,'r*')
hold on

plot(x2,y2,'r*')
hold on

sink = struct;    
sink.msg = 'temp';
sink.temp_value = '30'

source = struct;
source.msg = 'temp';
source.temp_value = '30'
```

Comment: You may want to add 4 spaces in front of the code bits of your question. It will make it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating an array of structures that stores *all* of the data associated with each "node". You can create all of the data for your nodes with one call to [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) in the following way:

```
N = 5;                         %# Number of nodes
coords = num2cell(rand(N,2));  %# Cell array of random x and y coordinates
nodes = struct('x',coords(:,1),...   %# Assign x coordinates
               'y',coords(:,2),...   %# Assign y coordinates
               'message','temp',...  %# Assign default message
               'value',30);          %# Assign default value
```

The variable `nodes` is an **N-by-1** structure array with fields `x`, `y`, `message`, and `value`. You can access and modify the data using the usual array and field indexing:

```
>> nodes(1)  %# Contents of node 1

ans = 

          x: 0.4387
          y: 0.4898
    message: 'temp'
      value: 30

>> nodes(1).message  %# Message for node 1

ans =

temp

>> nodes(1).message = 'hello world!';  %# Change message for node 1
```

You can then plot the nodes in the following way:

```
plot([nodes.x],[nodes.y],'r*');                %# Plot all the nodes in red
index = randi(N,[1 2]);                        %# Pick two nodes at random
hold on;
plot([nodes(index).x],[nodes(index).y],'b*');  %# Plot 2 random nodes in blue
```

Comment: hats off to you my friend, this  is exactly what i want, god bless u, u r genius

Comment: while running this code, it gives me following error, could you please check it my friend?

??? Undefined function or method 'randi' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> directeddiffusion at 10
index = randi(N,[1 2]);                        %# Pick two nodes at random

Comment: @gnovice : i tried using rand instead of randi, but it doesn't work. please have a look and tell me how to do, thanks

Comment: The function RANDI is only present in newer versions of MATLAB. I discuss another option to use in this answer to one of your other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816097/how-would-i-randomly-pick-one-point-from-n-points-in-matlab/1816333#1816333

Comment: @gnovice : as you told index= randi(N,[1 2]); will pick two nodes at random , but if i use index = ceil(rand*N); it picks only one node. but ,my code requirement is two nodes and what are those nodes.

Comment: I answered that in another one of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856141/how-do-i-randomly-select-k-points-from-n-points-in-matlab/1856201#1856201